# problem with intent - onClick compared to a onListItemClick

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using the following Intent to pass on to the next Screen were it shows user information that can be edited and saved.......This works good

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}
```

However on the Contact Screen I have a button and use the following to go to the Admin screen were you can edit and save other information, but when you click the button the screen goes black and terminates.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
String id = null;
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.admin: // doStuff
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Admin.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivity(i);   
    break;
```

I'm sure that the KEY_ROWID is the problem and needs to be recoded to work with a onClick compared to a onListItemClick....... Tryed alot but with no luck, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that in the first example the View that is passed in is the container for the row and in the second example it's just the button.